# Replace variable Nth occurence in file

Tags: awk, sed, while-loop, zsh

So I have a file with a bunch of occurrences of the same string across thousands of lines.
**For simplicity's sake**, my demo file reads as such:

```
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
```

I would like to replace each occurrence so that it reads

```
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0002
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0003
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0004
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0005
XXX
sss
```

I know I could do specific replacements of each line with

```
sed 's/0001/0002/2' file
```

But I was hoping that the following loop would work:

Though probably very slow, my original thought was to do

```
for k in *.txt; do
    x=0 #reset the number of occurrences to zero
    tconf=$(grep -c "cnum0001\n" $k) #find the total number of occurrences
    while $(( (($x + 0)) <= (($tconf + 0)) )); do #while the number of occurrences is less than the total number
        x=$(($x + 1)) #add one to the number of occurrences
        cnc=$(( printf %04d $x )) #set it so that $cnc includes the necessary number of leading zeroes before $x, so if x=1, cnc=0001.
        cn=${prefixCFGi}-cnum${cnc}
        sed -i 's/Fragment-cnum0001/$cn/$x' $k #This is the command I need help with. I want it to find the xth occurrence of Fragment-cnum0001 and replace it with $cn
    done #loop through the txt file until $x=$tconf
done #loop through all txt files
```

However, when I tried:

```
x=2;sed "s/0001/0002/$x" file
```

**the output was exactly the same as the input.** In this simple case, it should have merely changed the second occurrence of 0001 to 0002 and it did not. To me, this means that sed isn't understanding that x=2 and replacing it in the execution accordingly.

I am writing this as a part of a much larger zsh script, but I am currently working in the terminal.

Notes that I have added because the answers I was getting were not fully addressing my question:

1. I cannot use the line number as a counter (so code that says "do this every 4 lines" will not work). The number of lines between each occurrence is variable as is the text between them. **My actual file has over a hundred lines between each occurrence.**
2. I need to be able to specify the found string must be on its own line, as I have occurrences that are in the middle of a larger string on other lines that I do not want counted or replaced.

I am open to other commands, sed is just the one whose arrangement I am most familiar with.

Comment: This might help: `awk 'BEGIN {num=1} /^Fragment/ {printf("Fragment-cnum%04d\n", num); num++; next} 1'  file`

Comment: How true-to-life is that input sample? Does each record have 4 lines, and it's the 2nd line of each record that is changing? Does `awk 'NR % 4 == 2 {printf "alpha-cnum%04d\n", ++n; next} 1' file` do the job?

Comment: All of the included code, from `for *.txt` to the end of that loop, can be replaced with a single `awk` or other stream processing invocation on `*.txt`

Comment: you've stated *`replace each occurrence after the first`* but you *did* replace the first occurrence ... you replaced `Fragment` with `alpha` ... so not only are you incrementing a numeric portion you're also replacing a non-numeric string; also, will the string of interest be the only white-space delimited string on a line?

Comment: The basic idea of using a loop over the input file was not bad. You just have to fix the logic (such as the **nested** loop), remove the obvious errors (such as `$(( printf %04d $x ))`), and  avoid to create any child process inside the loop body,  because **this** is what makes it slow. I suggest that you first sketch the general **algorithm** for your problem on paper (this does not need any zsh knowledge; think of it in terms of any other programming language you are familiar with), and once you have found a reasonable algorithm, translate it into zsh.

Comment: @glennjackman "My actual file has over a hundred lines between each occurrence."

Comment: @markp-fuso The original question had me just counting, but people were ignoring the fact that I had set the replacement text to a VARIABLE and not just reusing the "Fragment-cnum" when they gave answers, so I changed it in hope to better reflect what I would be doing. I have removed the phrase in question.

Comment: @user1934428 I am glad that the loop is sound in principle. The ONLY line that I am having issues with is the sed line, but the answers I have been getting have all been ignoring some part of my (admittedly long and multipart) question.

Comment: The way you ask the question is not really helpful, since the code you posted is confusing and it is not clear where you got stuck. I would first outline the algorithm you have in mind in i.e. some [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) and then your attempt of translating it into zsh or awk (whatever language you prefer).

Comment: There are more problems. First, as I explained in my comment before, I strongly recommend against the use of `sed` here, unless you don't mind that the script takes long time. Second, if the `sed` line really is the **only** problem you are facing, rewrite your question describing what exactly this line is supposed to do, and in what way it does not produce the expected outcome.

Comment: I also don't understand what speaks again using a line number as a counter (though I don't see how this would be useful in your case either). Do you fear that you can get an integer overflow? To the best of my knowlege, zsh typically uses 8-byte-integer arithmetic, and I don't think you have files of a size that this can not be handled by a 64-bit-integer ;-)

Comment: it's not clear (to me) how you determine the numbering scheme; if all of the duplicate lines end in `0009` does that mean that after all replacements have been done you'll end up with `0009`, `0010`, `0011`? or will you always start numbering with `0002` on the 2nd occurrence so that you'll end up with `0009`, `0002`, `0003`? or will all duplicate rows *always* end in `0001`?

Comment: @markp-fuso The duplicate rows will ALWAYS end in 0001, and should then progress to 0002, 0003, 0004, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it would certainly be possible to use a `bash` loop to update the file, the repeated `sed -i` call is going to be excessive (ie, having to rewrite the entire file for each pass through the loop).  Better performance is going to come from using a tool (eg, `awk`, `perl`, `python`) that's capable of making the (multiple) changes in a single pass through the file.

Setup:

```
$ cat file1.txt
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss

$ cat file2.txt
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
```

One `awk` idea to replace OP's current `while` loop:

```
newpfx="alpha"

for k in *.txt
do
    printf "\n############## $k\n"

    awk -v pfx="Fragment,${newpfx}" '                    # define old/new prefix strings

    BEGIN     { split(pfx,a,",")                         # a[1]==old prefix / a[2]==new prefix
                oldid=a[1] "-cnum0001"                   # assumes always looking for string ending in "cnum0001"
                newid=a[2] "-cnum"
              }

    $1==oldid { $1 = newid sprintf("%04d", ++sfx) }      # if 1st field matches "oldid" then redefine 1st field; assumes no other fields on this line
    1                                                    # print current line
    ' "$k"
done
```

This generates:

```
############## file1.txt
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0002
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0003
XXX
sss

############## file2.txt
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
alpha-cnum0001
XXX
sss
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
alpha-cnum0002
XXX
sss
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
alpha-cnum0003
XXX
sss
```

If using `GNU awk` (for `-i inplace` support) we can directly update the files, eg:

```
newpfx="alpha"

for k in *.txt
do
    awk -i inplace -v pfx="Fragment,${newpfx}" '    
    BEGIN     { split(pfx,a,",")
                oldid=a[1] "-cnum0001"
                newid=a[2] "-cnum"
              }

    $1==oldid { $1 = newid sprintf("%04d", ++sfx) }
    1
    ' "$k"
done
```

This generates:

```
$ cat file1.txt
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0002
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
alpha-cnum0003
XXX
sss

$ cat file2.txt
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
alpha-cnum0001
XXX
sss
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
alpha-cnum0002
XXX
sss
456 Fragment-cnum0001 Mining
alpha-cnum0003
XXX
sss
```

We could go further and pull the `for k in *.txt` into our single `awk` call, eg:

```
awk -i inplace -v pfx="Fragment,${newpfx}" 'BEGIN ....' *.txt
```

OP will need to decide if this will work in the real script.

OP has mentioned this code is nested within a couple other loops; if those additional loops consist of making further modifications to these same files then it may be possible to pull those other loops into the same `awk` script, which in turn would improve the overall performance of the main script.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I want! My only question (I am not very familiar with the powerful awk) is "Is there a way to replace alpha in the pfx with a variable?" because that alpha is going to change depending on the file name.

Comment: @Pyrodancer123 updated the answer to use a variable (`newpfx`) to replace the hardcoded `alpha`; I've populated `newpfx` prior to the `for k in *.txt` but you could move it inside the `for k in *.txt` loop if its value will change with the file name

Answer (score 1):

(posted before question edits)

Perl allows some quick arithmetic within sed-like substitution syntax:

```
perl -pe 's/(Fragment-cnum)\d{4}/$1.sprintf("%04d",++$i)/e' file
```

This uses incrementer `$i` which implicitly starts at 0, but is incremented before each use.

In perl, `perl -pe` does stream processing where `-e` is the command for each line of input, like sed.

`s///e` syntax means the replacement side is a perl command to be evaluated, not a string.  So the `.` is perl's strcat operator.  Etc.

After update:

```
perl -pe "s/Fragment-cnum\d{4}/'$prefixCGI-cnum'.sprintf('%04d',++\$i)/e" *.txt
```

or this, to reset the index for each file and edit in place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/Fragment-cnum\d{4}/'$prefixCGI-cnum'.sprintf('%04d',++\$i)/e; \$i=0 if eof" *.txt
```

Comment: How do I combine the text used to replace with other variables? I defined $cn in my question because it will eventually read cn=$(( ${prefixCFGi}-cnum-${cnc})), where cnc is the 4 digit number.

Comment: That's where inline perl in the shell can get annoying, because perl uses variables beginning with $, too.  However you can pass shell vars with careful use of quotes, ie `perl -pe "s/foo/$bar/"` will have the shell evaluate $bar to its value before calling perl.   It might be quickest to put use double quotes around perl command and backslash escape the perl vars so they're not evaluated to null by the shell.

But if you're basically stream-processing the file in a broader script, you should probably handle everything in that stream, not call another.

Comment: I'm still new to this and have never used perl before. But this will be part of a MUCH larger zsh script and nestled within 3 different loops.

Answer (score 1):

An awk:

```
awk '/^Fragment/{sub(/0001/,sprintf("%04d", ++cnt))} 1' file 

123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0001
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0002
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0003
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0004
XXX
sss
123 Fragment-cnum0001 Energy
Fragment-cnum0005
XXX
sss
```

Comment: Unfortunately, what I am asking is not just a simple counting case. I need that number as a variable as well so I can define others. The text I am actually using to replace isn't going to contain the original "Fragment-cnum" at all.

Comment: You need a better example then.

Comment: I specifically asked "But is there a way for me to say
```
x=2
prefixCFGi=alpha
cnc=$(( printf %04d $x ))
cn=${prefixCFGi}-cnum${cnc}
sed 's/Fragment-cnum0001/$cn/$x' file
```
that way I can set x to a counter and adjust the $cn accordingly?"

Comment: You are still be very unclear what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

A `zsh`-only version:

```bash
prefixCFGi=alpha
for file in *.txt; do
  # read the entire contents of the file into an array of lines
  #  - <$file read input
  #  - $(...) substitute input as text
  #  - (f) split on newlins
  #  - (@), "" - ensure empty lines are included
  #  - typeset -a ...=(...) make an array
  typeset -a lines=("${(f@)$(<$file)}")
  integer cnum=0
  for idx in {1..$#lines}; do
    # change lines in array that match this exact string
    if [[ ${lines[idx]} == 'Fragment-cnum0001' ]]; then
      # construct replacement line with counter
      #  - $((...)) arithmetic operation
      #  - ++cnum increment and return value
      #  - (l:4::0:) - zero-pad number, 4 digits
      lines[idx]="${prefixCFGi}-cnum${(l:4::0:)$((++cnum))}"
    fi
  done
  # write array of lines to file, overwriting original
  print -l "${(@)lines}" >$file
done
```

This does not launch any subshells or other processes, so it should run fairly quickly. This will produce output similar to that from the other answers here; we're apparently not understanding all of the requirements, so you may need to adapt this to your needs.

Comment: This so far show the most promise. Would you mind annotating the commands? I'm not familiar with the typeset command you are using.